# QT real time graph has flickering problem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i am using openglseris (line) to display incoming data.
i  edited the opengl series example given by the qt as per my needs.

***How can I update the openglseris without flickering the display (smooth data update)***? Because so far I have managed to display incoming data but the display is flickering every time it updates the value.

```
//***********datasource.h**********//

    #ifndef DATASOURCE_H
#define DATASOURCE_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCharts/QXYSeries>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtCore/QElapsedTimer>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class DataSource : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataSource(QObject *parent = 0);

    void startUpdates(const QList<QXYSeries *> &seriesList, QLabel *fpsLabel);

public slots:
    void generateData(int seriesCount, int rowCount, int colCount);
    void update(QAbstractSeries *series, int seriesIndex);
    void handleSceneChanged();
    void updateAllSeries();

private:
    QVector<QVector<QVector<QPointF> > > m_data;
    int m_index;
    QList<QXYSeries *> m_seriesList;
    QLabel *m_fpsLabel;
    QElapsedTimer m_fpsTimer;
    QTimer m_dataUpdater;
};

#endif // DATASOURCE_H
```

```
//*************datasource.cpp*******************//

    #include "datasource.h"
#include <QtCore/QtMath>
#include<QDebug>
QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE
int shift=0;

int c[2048]={50,149,143,148,151,151,150,150,149,149,152,148,148,147,146,152,149,150,147,151,150,149,148,149,152,150,148,150,147,149,149,149,149,151,152,151,149,148,151,147,151,147,150,147,151,150,154,150,151,151,151,151,154,154,150,152,148,151,150,148,150,151,149,151,150,156,155,159,158,154,154,151,152,154,155,150,154,149,150,149,154,152,155,150,154,152,155,150,149,154,150,156,154,150,151,150,151,155,151,157,151,152,150,151,148,150,150,157,150,156,150,147,155,150,155,155,152,150,154,151,152,151,150,152,151,157,151,152,150,149,154,152,154,154,151,151,150,150,157,154,154,155,150,155,157,150,152,151,156,151,150,152,152,154,155,150,155,150,150,156,154,149,152,154,154,154,151,150,156,148,150,157,150,154,150,154,154,154,156,150,150,155,156,155,156,154,154,150,154,155,158,151,154,154,150,150,156,151,148,150,151,150,154,150,156,150,154,151,154,150,150,157,154,155,154,157,155,156,152,155,155,157,154,159,156,156,154,155,154,156,156,151,152,150,150,156,154,152,159,150,150,158,150,155,156,155,156,155,155,154,154,154,155,155,155,154,149,156,150,156,150,155,155,156,157,150,157,157,151,157,157,158,152,150,156,155,154,154,155,156,154,154,156,150,157,154,150,157,157,152,155,155,154,154,155,154,156,156,150,155,154,157,155,156,156,150,155,157,154,157,154,161,155,155,155,158,156,156,150,154,155,155,157,157,157,152,155,156,159,155,154,154,155,157,151,159,154,157,154,157,158,154,155,155,155,159,155,156,156,157,154,158,155,160,157,157,158,158,155,158,155,155,155,150,159,156,157,158,156,157,156,154,156,158,157,156,159,156,157,158,155,157,154,157,155,157,156,157,157,159,156,157,156,162,158,155,159,156,156,159,155,157,155,158,155,162,156,157,154,163,157,158,156,161,157,156,157,156,154,158,159,160,156,159,159,157,159,155,162,159,156,155,157,154,155,156,157,156,157,155,159,157,160,150,157,158,152,157,155,154,158,155,158,158,158,155,158,156,156,157,159,156,159,156,157,157,156,156,158,155,155,160,150,158,154,159,157,154,157,155,157,159,154,157,150,155,155,155,152,155,159,158,155,155,158,156,154,154,155,157,157,154,158,155,159,155,160,156,159,157,155,150,160,156,150,154,157,150,158,155,150,154,157,155,158,160,158,154,159,157,157,157,155,156,159,154,157,160,154,155,157,156,150,156,157,156,158,150,156,156,154,157,156,159,158,158,156,155,156,155,156,155,160,155,156,158,157,154,150,158,157,155,157,155,158,156,159,156,157,159,157,156,157,159,154,160,158,158,160,156,155,154,161,159,160,157,156,154,155,154,156,159,158,155,154,150,158,162,156,156,155,154,160,159,162,160,159,158,161,150,159,156,155,160,158,159,158,155,161,155,157,154,154,156,150,156,163,154,149,160,160,155,159,155,156,155,150,157,158,157,157,154,157,155,158,155,156,156,156,155,150,156,157,155,155,155,157,157,157,157,155,157,157,155,159,158,150,156,157,155,158,156,158,155,154,157,157,156,155,156,155,160,157,159,150,158,155,162,157,159,159,155,156,154,155,158,157,161,156,158,157,155,156,158,158,157,156,158,157,154,155,150,158,156,160,160,160,156,157,154,155,150,159,156,152,156,160,158,157,154,158,158,158,155,156,160,160,155,156,157,158,157,159,157,161,155,152,157,158,154,157,160,156,158,155,158,158,156,155,155,150,154,156,155,158,155,155,157,156,158,154,155,158,162,156,159,158,157,159,154,155,160,157,158,154,155,157,158,159,158,158,157,155,156,159,159,155,155,158,155,155,158,155,160,161,157,159,159,156,155,150,156,155,150,156,157,155,155,158,155,156,159,156,158,162,155,160,154,158,158,158,157,160,156,155,157,152,156,160,158,160,155,158,155,155,157,155,156,159,154,155,157,157,160,159,156,157,162,158,156,157,154,160,157,156,159,159,156,155,159,158,157,156,162,160,158,157,162,157,158,157,157,163,156,156,160,161,154,155,156,159,157,156,158,159,157,155,157,162,157,160,158,159,155,156,155,160,158,157,155,160,159,156,157,157,160,155,157,158,157,157,156,160,155,157,156,157,159,159,160,159,160,157,162,157,157,154,157,157,159,161,155,160,155,155,157,160,156,158,158,161,159,156,156,158,160,160,158,155,157,161,154,160,156,155,156,160,158,156,157,150,155,154,160,157,154,155,155,160,155,154,158,157,155,160,155,156,160,154,157,154,158,157,159,157,155,152,155,156,156,155,155,155,155,156,156,159,159,157,160,155,158,158,157,157,150,155,156,155,156,156,155,159,150,161,155,159,156,156,158,161,155,157,156,159,155,150,155,156,161,155,156,156,154,157,155,157,158,156,158,160,155,161,158,156,159,157,156,159,155,158,162,155,160,158,161,160,156,158,164,156,158,159,158,154,161,158,157,157,156,156,160,157,155,156,160,160,155,158,156,162,160,160,158,157,160,163,156,154,154,162,156,157,155,160,150,158,155,156,154,157,159,160,158,157,162,154,158,163,158,154,158,154,156,155,158,156,159,158,156,156,159,154,159,154,159,156,157,157,160,159,159,156,150,159,158,156,156,156,158,155,158,156,155,156,157,158,156,156,159,157,157,156,156,159,157,160,159,161,159,158,158,160,157,158,156,156,160,160,158,157,157,158,162,150,156,158,158,163,159,158,154,156,159,159,159,157,158,155,161,155,159,155,160,157,156,161,158,157,156,157,158,155,160,158,160,156,157,159,160,156,156,158,156,156,156,155,157,156,156,160,157,154,159,160,157,158,162,159,158,161,158,156,160,156,159,162,162,157,158,160,159,158,160,160,157,156,159,158,160,157,161,158,158,154,160,160,161,154,161,159,156,158,157,160,159,161,157,157,162,156,157,159,152,161,157,158,158,157,158,157,158,158,157,159,159,159,150,157,159,158,151,158,156,160,158,158,157,156,158,158,156,156,158,160,155,159,156,161,156,163,154,161,159,157,159,161,158,157,155,159,156,158,155,161,158,156,161,155,159,158,159,155,162,154,162,161,157,159,159,156,160,157,159,160,160,159,156,156,156,157,157,163,159,161,156,158,156,159,156,157,158,156,160,163,163,156,160,159,157,156,160,160,155,157,155,160,157,160,160,157,158,159,157,159,160,161,160,159,156,158,157,157,156,160,156,162,159,157,154,156,155,162,159,159,161,157,162,159,156,156,156,162,158,161,158,167,159,159,156,158,156,159,157,154,159,160,159,155,163,158,158,162,156,162,158,158,156,161,159,155,160,155,159,150,161,155,156,157,157,155,157,155,163,155,158,157,155,157,161,154,154,155,156,157,159,156,156,159,158,158,158,161,159,156,158,158,158,160,160,162,158,159,156,161,154,154,158,157,161,159,157,159,154,159,161,159,159,160,159,162,160,158,158,157,160,159,161,161,157,158,157,158,162,160,161,159,161,159,162,159,157,161,160,158,160,160,156,157,157,159,159,159,161,158,160,155,157,162,159,162,161,159,161,158,159,162,155,159,161,155,160,157,156,157,160,154,157,159,157,158,160,159,160,157,156,156,158,157,158,154,161,159,154,158,159,160,160,159,162,159,161,158,161,158,156,160,160,158,156,159,158,155,155,156,160,159,162,158,160,159,159,159,156,156,156,164,155,158,157,160,157,160,158,160,158,158,159,152,159,158,157,162,160,160,160,159,155,158,154,159,161,157,160,158,157,154,160,155,158,160,152,156,150,158,157,159,158,162,158,157,157,156,160,159,158,159,155,156,160,154,158,155,156,152,156,156,156,156,154,158,156,157,155,154,156,156,157,156,158,157,156,159,161,152,156,155,152,156,156,155,158,159,157,156,157,156,158,158,155,152,161,159,155,156,157,152,156,158,158,150,155,152,158,159,158,155,160,150,154,156,158,155,157,160,156,157,155,155,157,159,158,156,158,158,156,159,156,157,150,155,158,158,157,158,159,158,150,160,156,157,158,155,154,157,156,156,160,157,161,157,158,158,158,150,150,154,150,150,150,157,157,150,158,155,159,158,158,150,158,159,154,154,157,154,155,157,155,154,155,157,154,157,156,157,158,160,155,159,155,157,160,150,152,156,156,156,154,157,156,154,156,159,154,155,150,150,158,158,156,160,158,152,150,157,154,159,150,150,158,155,154,157,155,154,150,152,156,156,154,159,152,156,156,150,156,156,157,154,152,154,151,155,155,152,158,157,161,152,152,157,154,158,150,156,158,150,157,154,156,154,155,158,156,154,150,154,158,150,159,155,151,152,155,154,154,154,154,152,150,154,154,154,152,150,150,156,150,157,150,151,151,151,155,150,150,158,150,152,155,155,152,150,156,151,152,150,151,158,150,152,152,158,148,154,151,152,154,155,150,154,154,154,155,155,150,150,156,151,155,151,151,151,152,152,150,151,151,151,151,150,156,152,159,148,156,154,150,149,156,152,154,155,150,152,155,151,155,149,150,150,151,155,149,155,150,152,152,149,150,154,151,149,156,154,149,154,151,147,149,150,149,151,154,149,155,151,149,148,150,155,150,149,149,152,148,154,150,149,150,149,151,154,149,152,154,150,150,151,152,155,150,150,151,149,148,152,149};
int b[2048]={150,149,143,148,151,151,150,150,149,149,152,148,148,147,146,152,149,150,147,151,150,149,148,149,152,150,148,150,147,149,149,149,149,151,152,151,149,148,151,147,151,147,150,147,151,153,154,153,151,151,151,151,154,154,153,152,148,151,150,148,153,151,149,151,150,156,155,159,158,154,154,151,152,154,155,150,154,149,153,149,154,152,155,150,154,152,155,150,149,154,150,156,154,153,151,153,151,155,151,157,151,152,153,151,148,153,150,157,150,156,153,147,155,150,155,155,152,153,154,151,152,151,153,152,151,157,151,152,153,149,154,152,154,154,151,151,153,153,157,154,154,155,153,155,157,153,152,151,156,151,153,152,152,154,155,153,155,150,150,156,154,149,152,154,154,154,151,150,156,148,150,157,153,154,153,154,154,154,156,150,150,155,156,155,156,154,154,153,154,155,158,151,154,154,153,153,156,151,148,153,151,153,154,153,156,153,154,151,154,153,153,157,154,155,154,157,155,156,152,155,155,157,154,159,156,156,154,155,154,156,156,151,152,153,153,156,154,152,159,150,153,158,153,155,156,155,156,155,155,154,154,154,155,155,155,154,149,156,153,156,153,155,155,156,157,150,157,157,151,157,157,158,152,153,156,155,154,154,155,156,154,154,156,153,157,154,150,157,157,152,155,155,154,154,155,154,156,156,153,155,154,157,155,156,156,153,155,157,154,157,154,161,155,155,155,158,156,156,153,154,155,155,157,157,157,152,155,156,159,155,154,154,155,157,151,159,154,157,154,157,158,154,155,155,155,159,155,156,156,157,154,158,155,160,157,157,158,158,155,158,155,155,155,153,159,156,157,158,156,157,156,154,156,158,157,156,159,156,157,158,155,157,154,157,155,157,156,157,157,159,156,157,156,162,158,155,159,156,156,159,155,157,155,158,155,162,156,157,154,163,157,158,156,161,157,156,157,156,154,158,159,160,156,159,159,157,159,155,162,159,156,155,157,154,155,156,157,156,157,155,159,157,160,153,157,158,152,157,155,154,158,155,158,158,158,155,158,156,156,157,159,156,159,156,157,157,156,156,158,155,155,160,153,158,154,159,157,154,157,155,157,159,154,157,153,155,155,155,152,155,159,158,155,155,158,156,154,154,155,157,157,154,158,155,159,155,160,156,159,157,155,153,160,156,150,154,157,153,158,155,153,154,157,155,158,160,158,154,159,157,157,157,155,156,159,154,157,160,154,155,157,156,153,156,157,156,158,153,156,156,154,157,156,159,158,158,156,155,156,155,156,155,160,155,156,158,157,154,153,158,157,155,157,155,158,156,159,156,157,159,157,156,157,159,154,160,158,158,160,156,155,154,161,159,160,157,156,154,155,154,156,159,158,155,154,153,158,162,156,156,155,154,160,159,162,160,159,158,161,153,159,156,155,160,158,159,158,155,161,155,157,154,154,156,153,156,163,154,149,160,160,155,159,155,156,155,153,157,158,157,157,154,157,155,158,155,156,156,156,155,153,156,157,155,155,155,157,157,157,157,155,157,157,155,159,158,153,156,157,155,158,156,158,155,154,157,157,156,155,156,155,160,157,159,153,158,155,162,157,159,159,155,156,154,155,158,157,161,156,158,157,155,156,158,158,157,156,158,157,154,155,153,158,156,160,160,160,156,157,154,155,153,159,156,152,156,160,158,157,154,158,158,158,155,156,160,160,155,156,157,158,157,159,157,161,155,152,157,158,154,157,160,156,158,155,158,158,156,155,155,153,154,156,155,158,155,155,157,156,158,154,155,158,162,156,159,158,157,159,154,155,160,157,158,154,155,157,158,159,158,158,157,155,156,159,159,155,155,158,155,155,158,155,160,161,157,159,159,156,155,153,156,155,153,156,157,155,155,158,155,156,159,156,158,162,155,160,154,158,158,158,157,160,156,155,157,152,156,160,158,160,155,158,155,155,157,155,156,159,154,155,157,157,160,159,156,157,162,158,156,157,154,160,157,156,159,159,156,155,159,158,157,156,162,160,158,157,162,157,158,157,157,163,156,156,160,161,154,155,156,159,157,156,158,159,157,155,157,162,157,160,158,159,155,156,155,160,158,157,155,160,159,156,157,157,160,155,157,158,157,157,156,160,155,157,156,157,159,159,160,159,160,157,162,157,157,154,157,157,159,161,155,160,155,155,157,160,156,158,158,161,159,156,156,158,160,160,158,155,157,161,154,160,156,155,156,160,158,156,157,153,155,154,160,157,154,155,155,160,155,154,158,157,155,160,155,156,160,154,157,154,158,157,159,157,155,152,155,156,156,155,155,155,155,156,156,159,159,157,160,155,158,158,157,157,153,155,156,155,156,156,155,159,153,161,155,159,156,156,158,161,155,157,156,159,155,153,155,156,161,155,156,156,154,157,155,157,158,156,158,160,155,161,158,156,159,157,156,159,155,158,162,155,160,158,161,160,156,158,164,156,158,159,158,154,161,158,157,157,156,156,160,157,155,156,160,160,155,158,156,162,160,160,158,157,160,163,156,154,154,162,156,157,155,160,153,158,155,156,154,157,159,160,158,157,162,154,158,163,158,154,158,154,156,155,158,156,159,158,156,156,159,154,159,154,159,156,157,157,160,159,159,156,153,159,158,156,156,156,158,155,158,156,155,156,157,158,156,156,159,157,157,156,156,159,157,160,159,161,159,158,158,160,157,158,156,156,160,160,158,157,157,158,162,153,156,158,158,163,159,158,154,156,159,159,159,157,158,155,161,155,159,155,160,157,156,161,158,157,156,157,158,155,160,158,160,156,157,159,160,156,156,158,156,156,156,155,157,156,156,160,157,154,159,160,157,158,162,159,158,161,158,156,160,156,159,162,162,157,158,160,159,158,160,160,157,156,159,158,160,157,161,158,158,154,160,160,161,154,161,159,156,158,157,160,159,161,157,157,162,156,157,159,152,161,157,158,158,157,158,157,158,158,157,159,159,159,153,157,159,158,151,158,156,160,158,158,157,156,158,158,156,156,158,160,155,159,156,161,156,163,154,161,159,157,159,161,158,157,155,159,156,158,155,161,158,156,161,155,159,158,159,155,162,154,162,161,157,159,159,156,160,157,159,160,160,159,156,156,156,157,157,163,159,161,156,158,156,159,156,157,158,156,160,163,163,156,160,159,157,156,160,160,155,157,155,160,157,160,160,157,158,159,157,159,160,161,160,159,156,158,157,157,156,160,156,162,159,157,154,156,155,162,159,159,161,157,162,159,156,156,156,162,158,161,158,167,159,159,156,158,156,159,157,154,159,160,159,155,163,158,158,162,156,162,158,158,156,161,159,155,160,155,159,153,161,155,156,157,157,155,157,155,163,155,158,157,155,157,161,154,154,155,156,157,159,156,156,159,158,158,158,161,159,156,158,158,158,160,160,162,158,159,156,161,154,154,158,157,161,159,157,159,154,159,161,159,159,160,159,162,160,158,158,157,160,159,161,161,157,158,157,158,162,160,161,159,161,159,162,159,157,161,160,158,160,160,156,157,157,159,159,159,161,158,160,155,157,162,159,162,161,159,161,158,159,162,155,159,161,155,160,157,156,157,160,154,157,159,157,158,160,159,160,157,156,156,158,157,158,154,161,159,154,158,159,160,160,159,162,159,161,158,161,158,156,160,160,158,156,159,158,155,155,156,160,159,162,158,160,159,159,159,156,156,156,164,155,158,157,160,157,160,158,160,158,158,159,152,159,158,157,162,160,160,160,159,155,158,154,159,161,157,160,158,157,154,160,155,158,160,152,156,153,158,157,159,158,162,158,157,157,156,160,159,158,159,155,156,160,154,158,155,156,152,156,156,156,156,154,158,156,157,155,154,156,156,157,156,158,157,156,159,161,152,156,155,152,156,156,155,158,159,157,156,157,156,158,158,155,152,161,159,155,156,157,152,156,158,158,150,155,152,158,159,158,155,160,150,154,156,158,155,157,160,156,157,155,155,157,159,158,156,158,158,156,159,156,157,153,155,158,158,157,158,159,158,153,160,156,157,158,155,154,157,156,156,160,157,161,157,158,158,158,153,153,154,153,153,153,157,157,150,158,155,159,158,158,153,158,159,154,154,157,154,155,157,155,154,155,157,154,157,156,157,158,160,155,159,155,157,160,153,152,156,156,156,154,157,156,154,156,159,154,155,153,153,158,158,156,160,158,152,153,157,154,159,153,153,158,155,154,157,155,154,153,152,156,156,154,159,152,156,156,153,156,156,157,154,152,154,151,155,155,152,158,157,161,152,152,157,154,158,153,156,158,153,157,154,156,154,155,158,156,154,153,154,158,153,159,155,151,152,155,154,154,154,154,152,153,154,154,154,152,153,153,156,153,157,153,151,151,151,155,153,153,158,153,152,155,155,152,153,156,151,152,153,151,158,153,152,152,158,148,154,151,152,154,155,153,154,154,154,155,155,153,153,156,151,155,151,151,151,152,152,150,151,151,151,151,150,156,152,159,148,156,154,150,149,156,152,154,155,153,152,155,151,155,149,153,150,151,155,149,155,153,152,152,149,153,154,151,149,156,154,149,154,151,147,149,153,149,151,154,149,155,151,149,148,150,155,150,149,149,152,148,154,153,149,150,149,151,154,149,152,154,153,150,151,152,155,153,150,151,149,148,152,149 };
DataSource::DataSource(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_index(-1)
{
    generateData(0, 0, 0);
}

void DataSource::update(QAbstractSeries *series, int seriesIndex)
{
    if (series) {
        QXYSeries *xySeries = static_cast<QXYSeries *>(series);
        const QVector<QVector<QPointF> > &seriesData = m_data.at(seriesIndex);
        if (seriesIndex == 0)
            m_index++;
        if (m_index > seriesData.count() - 1)
            m_index = 0;

        QVector<QPointF> points = seriesData.at(m_index);
        // Use replace instead of clear + append, it's optimized for performance
        xySeries->replace(points);
    }
}

void DataSource::handleSceneChanged()
{
    m_dataUpdater.start();
}

void DataSource::updateAllSeries()
{
    static int frameCount = 0;
    static QString labelText = QStringLiteral("FPS: %1");

    for (int i = 0; i < m_seriesList.size(); i++)
        update(m_seriesList[i], i);
    frameCount++;
    int elapsed = m_fpsTimer.elapsed();
    if (elapsed >= 1000) {
        elapsed = m_fpsTimer.restart();
        qreal fps = qreal(0.1 * int(10000.0 * (qreal(frameCount) / qreal(elapsed))));
        m_fpsLabel->setText(labelText.arg(QString::number(fps, 'f', 1)));
        m_fpsLabel->adjustSize();
        frameCount = 0;
    }
    m_data.clear();
    // Append the new data depending on the type

        QVector<QVector<QPointF> > seriesData;
            QVector<QPointF> points;
           // points.reserve(2048);
            for (int j(0); j < 2048; j++) {
                qreal x(0);
                qreal y(0);
                   if(shift==0)
                   {
                        y = b[j] ;
                        x=j;
                   }else
                   {
                       y = c[j] ;
                       x=j;
                   }
                points.append(QPointF(x, y));
            }
            seriesData.append(points);
        m_data.append(seriesData);
    if(shift==0)
    {
        shift=1;
    }else
    {
        shift=0;
    }

}

void DataSource::startUpdates(const QList<QXYSeries *> &seriesList, QLabel *fpsLabel)
{
    m_seriesList = seriesList;
    m_fpsLabel = fpsLabel;

    m_dataUpdater.setInterval(500);
    m_dataUpdater.setSingleShot(true);
    QObject::connect(&m_dataUpdater, &QTimer::timeout,this, &DataSource::updateAllSeries);

    m_fpsTimer.start();
    updateAllSeries();

}

void DataSource::generateData(int seriesCount, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    // Remove previous data
   foreach (QVector<QVector<QPointF> > seriesData, m_data) {
       foreach (QVector<QPointF> row, seriesData)
           row.clear();
   }
   m_data.clear();

    // Append the new data depending on the type
    for (int k(0); k < seriesCount; k++) {
        QVector<QVector<QPointF> > seriesData;

        for (int i(0); i < rowCount; i++) {
            QVector<QPointF> points;
            points.reserve(colCount);
            for (int j(0); j < colCount; j++) {
                qreal x(0);
                qreal y(0);
                   if(shift==0)
                   {
                        y = a[j] ;
                        x=j;
                   }else
                   {
                       y = b[j] ;
                       x=j;
                   }
                points.append(QPointF(x, y));
            }
            seriesData.append(points);
        }
        m_data.append(seriesData);
    }

    if(shift==0)
    {
        shift=1;
    }else
    {
        shift=0;
    }
    qDebug()<<"test";
}
```

```
//***********main.cpp**********//

#include "datasource.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QScatterSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QLogValueAxis>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QStringList colors;
    colors << "red" << "blue" << "green" << "black";

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();



    QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis;
    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis;


    chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
    chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);

    const int seriesCount = 1;

    const int pointCount = 2048;
    chart->setTitle("OpenGL Accelerated Series");


    QList<QXYSeries *> seriesList;
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
        QXYSeries *series = 0;
        int colorIndex = i % colors.size();
        if (i % 2) {
            series = new QScatterSeries;
            QScatterSeries *scatter = static_cast<QScatterSeries *>(series);
            scatter->setColor(QColor(colors.at(colorIndex)));
            scatter->setMarkerSize(qreal(colorIndex + 2) / 2.0);
            // Scatter pen doesn't have affect in OpenGL drawing, but if you disable OpenGL drawing
            // this makes the marker border visible and gives comparable marker size to OpenGL
            // scatter points.
            scatter->setPen(QPen("black"));
        } else {
            series = new QLineSeries;
            series->setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(colors.at(colorIndex))),
                                qreal(colorIndex + 2) / 2.0));
        }
        seriesList.append(series);

        //![1]
        series->setUseOpenGL(true);
        //![1]

        chart->addSeries(series);
        series->attachAxis(axisX);
        series->attachAxis(axisY);
    }

    if (axisX->type() == QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeLogValue)
        axisX->setRange(0.1, 2048.0);
    else
        axisX->setRange(0, 2048.0);

    if (axisY->type() == QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeLogValue)
        axisY->setRange(0.1, 255.0);
    else
        axisY->setRange(0, 255.0);



    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(600, 400);
    window.show();

    DataSource dataSource;
    dataSource.generateData(seriesCount, 1, pointCount);

    QLabel *fpsLabel = new QLabel(&window);
    QLabel *countLabel = new QLabel(&window);
    QString countText = QStringLiteral("Total point count: %1");
    countLabel->setText(countText.arg(pointCount * seriesCount));
    countLabel->adjustSize();
    fpsLabel->move(10, 2);
    fpsLabel->adjustSize();
    fpsLabel->raise();
    fpsLabel->show();
    countLabel->move(10, fpsLabel->height());
    fpsLabel->raise();
    countLabel->show();

    // We can get more than one changed event per frame, so do async update.
    // This also allows the application to be responsive.
    QObject::connect(chart->scene(), &QGraphicsScene::changed,
                     &dataSource, &DataSource::handleSceneChanged);

    dataSource.startUpdates(seriesList, fpsLabel);

    return a.exec();
}
```